# How to use Fubini's Theorem to find a function $g(z)$

Tags: calculus, integration, fubini-tonelli-theorems

Use Fubini's Theorem to find a function $g(z)$ such that
$\int_0^a\int_0^x\int_0^y f(z)\,dz\,dy\,dx=\int_0^a g(z)f(z)\,dz$ where $a$ is a real number.

I tried to use Fubini's Theorem,

$$\int_0^a\int_0^x\int_0^y f(z)\,dz\,dy\,dx
=\int_0^a\int_z^a\int_z^x f(z)\,dy\,dx\,dz
=\int_0^a (z^{2}/2+a^{2}/2-2a)f(z)\,dz$$

Hence, $g(z)=z^{2}/2+a^{2}/2-2a$.

Is it correct? Or I need to write more steps?
Can any give me an answer?

Comment: Your answer is wrong, if $f(z)\equiv1$ the left side gives $a^3/6$ bu the right sid is equals to $a^2/2$.

Comment: @DiegoMath Can you give me a correct answer? I am confused that how to finish it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
& \int_0^a \left( \int_0^x \left( \int_0^y f(z)\,dz \right) \,dy \right) \,dx \\[10pt]
= {} & \iiint\limits_{(x,y,z)\,:\, 0\,\le\,z\,\le\,y\,\le\,x\,\le\,a} f(z)\, d(z,y,x) \\[10pt]
= {} & \int_0^a \left( \int_z^a \left( \int_z^x f(z) \, dy \right)   \,dx \right) \, dz
\end{align}
As $y$ goes from $z$ to $x$ and $x$ goes from $z$ to $a,$ the value of $f(z)$ does not change, so it can be pulled out of the two inner integrals:
$$
\int_0^a f(z) \left( \int_z^a \left( \int_z^x 1 \, dy \right) \, dx \right) \, dz
$$
So
\begin{align}
g(z) = {} & \int_z^a \left( \int_z^x 1 \, dy \right) \, dx \\[8pt]
= {} & \int_z^a (x-z) \, dx = \left[ \frac {x^2} 2 - zx \right]_{x:=z}^{x:=a} \\[8pt]
= {} & \left( \frac {a^2} 2 - az \right) - \left( \frac{z^2} 2 - z^2 \right) = \frac{a^2-z^2} 2 - (az-z^2) \\[8pt]
= {} & \frac{(a-z)^2} 2.
\end{align}

Comment: why as $y$ goes from $z$ to $x$ and $x$ goes from $z$ to $a$, the value of $f(z)$ does not change? How to check this result?

Comment: @Hung218 : In the outermost integral $\displaystyle \int_0^a \cdots\, dz,$ you have $z$ running from $0$ to $a.$ The two other integrals are, as the notation suggests, INSIDE that integral. That means for some particular value of $z,$ the variables $x,y$ run through some particular set depending on $z. \qquad$

Comment: okay, thank you so much